# Java stuck waiting for slow MySQL query that has finished executing server side, no error thrown

Tags: java, mysql

I am querying a remote MySQL server with a java program. The queries are select statements that may take anywhere from a minute to half an hour. The size of the data returned is always the same (I am counting rows).

The program usually executes without any problems, but sometimes it gets stuck at one of the longer queries. It doesn't abort (java program is still "running") and there is no error thrown. When I check the MySQL server process list, the query is not listed, and the error log is empty as well, so I assume it has finished executing.

I have a print directly before and after every query, so i know for certain that the program gets stuck with the query.

I thought it was a connection time out problem, so I set autoreconnect to true, but it didn't help. I am pretty clueless about how to solve this since there is no error thrown.

Java code looks like this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
DBConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(DBConnectionURL);
DBStatement=DBConnection.createStatement();

// being of loop
System.out.println("starting query " +selectQuery);
qA=DBStatement.executeQuery(selectQuery);
System.out.println("finished query " +selectQuery);
// do sth with query
// end of loop
```

If the program gets stuck, the last output is always a `starting query [..]`

Comment: Is the log after the query executed just below the call? Do you have a log in case an exception is thrown?

Comment: did you run that longer query in Toad separately what was the result.how are you so sure that its only that particular query. did you check for database locking if you may be using.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos could you rephrase that?

Comment: @vikeng21 the program will execute fine most of the time, only sometimes it will get stuck. the queries are always the same, so i know that they are working. i know that it's a particular query because i see the System.out.println("got to point X") before and after every query. can you elaborate on the database locking?

Comment: Could you show the java code that you are using to call MySQL?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos have added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the java code you pasted the error is this:

You are calling MySQL and printing "starting query ....", the one of two things happen: either the query works, and you see the "finished query ..." or an exception is thrown and the "finished query ..." is skipped and the execution goes to the code that handles the exception.

What kinds of exceptions would cause this:

if the selectQuery is something that is modified dynamically then it could be a malformed query exception.

if the selectQuery is not dynamic and it works, it could be its parameters.

If the selectQuery is good and the parameters are good than it could be a connection timeout issue: your sql is taking longer than the time set in the java connection.

To know for sure you have to print the stacktrace of the exception in the "catch/finally" block. It will reveal to you what the problem was. A simple google search with the cause of the problem should tell you how to fix it.

Comment: There is no exception thrown, that is why I cannot identify the issue.

Comment: Paste the whole code, from where you get the exception to where you close the connection.

Comment: I do not get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the result set? The MySQL JDBC connector buffers all rows before returning, so you could just be seeing that lag.

Comment: The result set is always the same size, and the program executes fine most of the time, so this cannot be the problem.